# TIAGo installation kinetic - packages names?

Tags: ros, installation, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ubuntu 16.04 and ROS kinetic. At [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/TIAGo/Tutorials/Installation/InstallUbuntuAndROS) there is just information for ROS indigo. Any idea what is with two packages which are not listed at kinetic anymore?

```
andrejpan@t530:~/ros/workspace/tiago_ws$ sudo apt-get install git python-rosinstall ros-kinetic-desktop-full python-catkin-tools ros-kinetic-joint-state-controller ros-kinetic-twist-mux ros-kinetic-ompl ros-kinetic-controller-manager ros-kinetic-moveit-ros-move-group ros-kinetic-moveit-ros-planning-interface ros-kinetic-moveit-simple-controller-manager ros-kinetic-moveit-planners-ompl ros-kinetic-joy ros-kinetic-joy-teleop ros-kinetic-teleop-tools ros-kinetic-control-toolbox ros-kinetic-sound-play ros-kinetic-navigation ros-kinetic-eband-local-planner ros-kinetic-depthimage-to-laserscan ros-kinetic-ddynamic-reconfigure-python ros-kinetic-openslam-gmapping ros-kinetic-gmapping
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-eband-local-planner

E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-ddynamic-reconfigure-python
```

Best, Andrej

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247244/tiago-installation-kinetic---packages-names?/) by [andrejpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28435/andrejpan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-11-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at (for instance) [wiki/tiago_description](http://wiki.ros.org/tiago_description), those packages are not released for anything but Indigo. The wiki instructions you link to also specifically only mention Indigo.

As to `eband-local-planner` and `ddynamic-reconfigure-python`: looking at [status_page/ros_kinetic_default.html?q=eband](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_kinetic_default.html?q=eband) and [status_page/ros_kinetic_default.html?q=ddynamic](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_kinetic_default.html?q=ddynamic), those packages have not been released into Kinetic. And as far as I can find out, those packages were also not removed (using the [2016-10-04 Kinetic sync](http://discourse.ros.org/t/new-packages-for-kinetic-2016-10-04/544) announcement fi, search for *Removed Packages*).

Have you ever been able to install those packages on Kinetic?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [andrejpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28435/andrejpan/) on 2016-11-05**:
I found from people at university that Tiago software works only at Indigo, yeas.

This entry is misleading at [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/TIAGo/Tutorials/Installation/TiagoSimulation). Somebody should remove tabs which shows other than Indigo distributions or make them completely empty.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-05**:
The version rocker (the 'tabs' you refer to) says this when you click on Kinetic:

> **Coming soon! Currently supported: indigo.**

so it does explicitly tell you which version is supported. Perhaps that could be made more visible. I suggest you report this to PAL.